# using wildcard in Perl in dir name matching

Tags: perl

```
my @hex_locations = ("$FindBin::Bin/../../../project/platform-aa-full/bb",
                     "$FindBin::Bin/../../../project/platform-aa-base/bb");
```

how do I use wild card to match any directory with project/platform-aa-* in above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)

```
my @hex_locations = glob("$FindBin::Bin/../../../project/platform-aa-*/bb");
```